# How can I force a numeral to be stored NumberLong() in mongo using the php mongo driver?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an API that expects for a certain field to have `NumberLong` values. Therefore, when writing to the with the database with the PHP driver, these values should be written as type `NumberLong`. [Here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/525#issuecomment-278395545) it is stated that

> When the driver encodes a PHP integer to BSON (here), we use a macro
> that writes a 64-bit or 32-bit integer depending on the range of the
> PHP integer value. This is analogous to the server's behavior, where
> results of integer computation (e.g. from an $inc) will use the
> smallest type able to contain the value and roll over to the large
> type as needed.

As far as I can tell, this is still the case.

This program recreates the problem:

```
// document with _id=0 looks like: {"_id": 0, "number": NumberLong(42)}
$collection = (new \DB\Mongo())->selectCollection("test");
$docs = $collection->find(["_id" => 0]);
foreach ($docs as $doc) {
  $doc["_id"] = 1;
  $doc["number"] = 42;
  $collection->insertOne($doc);
}
// document with _id=1 looks like: {"_id": 1, "number": 42}
```

The goal is to "copy" some documents, making simple modifications. PHP is used for historical reasons.

How can I *force* the `"number"` field in the above document _id=1 to be `NumberLong(42)` as it is with _id=0 ?

Comment: This seems to be impossible.

Comment: That's pretty discouraging to hear.

Answer (score 0):

I parsed some extended json with the php driver and type information was lost, leading me to believe that the driver doesn't provide a straightforward way to preserve types. Int64 carries with it a note that it isn't instantiable directly.

With that said, a driver technically isn't obligated to preserve type information for its own functionality except in case of cursor ids which must be sent to the server as int64s. Based on this I suggest the following:

- Execute a find and get a cursor. Retrieve its cursor id.
- Serialize the cursor id. It's basically an int64.
- Look at the serialized representation to figure out where the value is.
- Construct a new serialized representation with the int64 value you want.
- Deserialize a cursor id from this representation.
- Use the cursor id in your operation where you want to send the int64.

Somewhat of a crazy idea but it might work.

Comment: I'll try first chance I get and report back. Thanks.